# Is there a Linux driver for testing transport protocols?

Tags: linux, testing, driver, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I am trying to test some communication protocols, both commercial and homegrown. I would like to find an Ethernet driver that allows me to degrade the channel in a controllable fashion. For instance

1. specify a packet drop rate.
2. modulate the bandwidth.
3. modulate the RTT, independent of the apparent bandwidth

This may all be done performing "tricks" to the real driver's input queue. So I would simply load the driver pointing it at target existing channel and perform my tests on the new port. Anyone know if such a driver exists?

Comment: Well, I know of a tool called Netem (it's an extension to netfilters) that does what you want, but works at ip level - http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for, this and dummynet combined with a few sripts, thanks Fred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netem does what you want at ip level.

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: I dropped dummnet to use token bucket, which is already built into Linux, thanks again Fred